# Как пропустить ошибку при клике на кнопку

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser=webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://ru.com/')
submit=browser.find_element_by_css_selector ("a.follow_tooltip_button")
submit.click()

browser.get('https://ru.com/')
submit=browser.find_element_by_css_selector ("a.follow_tooltip_button")
submit.click()
```

Как пропустить ошибку о ненахождении элемента что бы программа продолжила работу

```
   Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: a.follow_tooltip_button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно пропуск exception - свидетельство непродуманной логики, но отвечаю на вопрос:

Подробное описание находится по [ссылке](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html)

А именно нас интересует вот этот кусок кода

```
try:
   k = 1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
   k = 0
```

Тут мы пытаемся поделить на ноль и поймав исключен в блоке кода от try до except обрабатываем в блоке except. Когда мы делим на ноль, мы ловим исключение и делаем K = 0.

В вашем случае после `except BaseException:` обрабатывать ничего не надо, тем самым вы пропустите исключение. Если вы укажите `except BaseException:`, то пропустите обработку всех исключений в нужно вам блоке(т.к BaseException базовый для всех).

P.S. Если для вас ответ оказался верным и вы считаете, что отвечавший ответил на вопрос, стоит пометить ответ ответом(галочка у сообщения), для того, чтобы другие пользователи, когда открыли вопрос, смогли быстро понять, что в итоге является ответом(а точнее что сработало для автора вопроса и что он посчитал верным в данной ситуации)

Comment: Не запускается try:
  browser.get ("https://ru.ru")
  submit=browser.find_element_by_css_selector ("a.follow_tooltip_button")
  sumbit.click()
  except BaseException:

Comment: Возможно т.к вы ничего не написали в блоке except. Впишите туда, например, print(e.message)

Comment: замените except BaseException: на except BaseException as e:, а потом print(e.message)

Comment: Вы таким образом обзывете Exception как е, чтобы дальше с ним удобно было работать. А далее просто выводим сообщение об исключении(но программа будет работать дальше)

Comment: Я разобрался спасибо большое

Comment: @Петя не забудьте отметить ответ. На ресурсе так принято.